# Heroku CI/CD with npm private packages

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, heroku-ci

Anyone have any ideas what the issue here is, it seems to be evaluating my npm registry to False. I am installing packages from a private scope.
I have added an .npmrc file as well and added

```
@scope:registry=https://registry.npm.org
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_PRIVATE_TOKEN}
```

When I echo the variable from heroku in my console I see that NPM_PRIVATE_TOKEN is already set

```
heroku config:get NPM_PRIVATE_TOKEN --app xxxxx
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx
```

```html
Total 530 (delta 244), reused 331 (delta 140)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=False
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  12.x.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   6.x.x
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 12.x.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.18.4...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 6.x.x (replacing 6.14.6)...
remote:        npm 6.x.x installed
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        npm ERR! code E404
remote:        npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/False - Not found
remote:        npm ERR! 404 
remote:        npm ERR! 404  'False@latest' is not in the npm registry.
remote:        npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because 
remote:        npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
remote:        npm ERR! 404 
remote:        npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
remote:        npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.QbXAj/_logs/2020-09-24T17_46_48_753Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
rem
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this was a silly error on my part I was setting my env variables and accidentally set
`NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` to `False` instead of `false`.